# Identity theorem f(z) isn't holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show that $f(z)=\exp((1+i)|z|)$ isn't holomorphic on any open disk using the identity theorem. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists an open disk $\Delta(z_0;r)$ in which $f(z)$ is analytic. The functions $f(z)$ and $$\exp((1+i)|z_0|) $$ coincide on the circular arc $\Delta(z_0;r) \cap \{|z|=|z_0| \}$. Thus according to the identity theorem, they must agree in the entire disk. This is clearly false, since $f$ is nonconstant.

Comment: Thank you! I only don't understand the notation $\Delta(z_0;r)$. I meant an open sphere instead of an open disk. So I think $\Delta(z_0;r)$ must be $B(z_0;r)$?

Comment: @RoosJansen $\Delta(z_0;r)=\{z:|z-z_0|<r \}$. This notation appears in Ahlfors' text.